# Novel: The apocalypse began, monsters spawned and people got special powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel I read a year or so ago where the main character was injured. When the apocalypse began, monsters spawned and people got special powers. MC's main power was ice. MC used knowledge from the future to use crystals from the bodies of the monsters to power up while protecting his sister. I distinctly remember him creating weapons out of ice and condensing them to increase their power. Not LitRPG or GameLit. MC has an older brother who was overseas when the apocalypse hit and leads a mercenary company?

Comment: Did you read this as a hardback book? Paperback? Kindle? Online? Did it seem like it was translated from another language?

Comment: You _read_ it a year or so ago, but was it new when you read it or was it years/decades old?